# best practice for comparing two NSArray's & populating a third with the objects that don't appear in both?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm new to iOS and objective C and am trying to come up with things I can do to experiment and teach myself. I'd also like to learn to do things the right way, which can be difficult while learning on your own.

I'd like to take 2 NSArray's that might look like

Array1:
- Object1: @"Hello"
- Object2: @"This"
- Object3: @"Is a"
- Object4: @"Test"

Array2:
- Object1: @"Hello"
- Object2: @"Is a"

and create a third array that contains those objects that didn't appear in both array's that I've compared, so the result would be

Array3:
- Object1: @"This"
- Object2: @"Test"

I figured I could run through each array and run through each object with a foreach that would compare each object to the list of objects in the second array, adding array1's object to array3 if it's not found.

I'm new to memory management (I know ARC is here but I'm trying to be old school for now, everywhere I look says it's an important skill to learn) so I'm just trying to find out if there's a better way to do this.

thanks in advance for any help, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to operate with sets.

Symmetric difference in Objective C:

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Hello", @"This", @"Is a", @"Test", nil];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Hello", @"Is a", nil];

NSMutableSet *notInSet1 = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:set2];
[notInSet1 minusSet:set1];
NSMutableSet *notInSet2 = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:set1];
[notInSet2 minusSet:set2];

NSMutableSet *symmetricDifference = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:notInSet1];
[symmetricDifference unionSet:notInSet2];
```

The reason why you should use sets for your task is because sets contain unique objects (i.e. they can't contain two `@"42"` `NSString` objects), and this is preferable when you need operations like intersection or difference or union.

Comment: It might be helpful to others. There may be plenty of newbies that can't make the connection from the question's original arrays to your uninitialized `NSSet` variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. If you want to do it using the framework arrays methods this could be a good way:

```
NSArray *Array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
NSArray *Array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Two", @"Four", @"One", nil];
NSMutableArray *Array3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:Array1];
[intermediate removeObjectsInArray:Array2];
```

You dont need to care about releasing this arrays since they are returned autoreleased from arraywithObjects and arrayWithArray.

Comment: This doesn't work properly. The final array should have `@"Three"` and `@"Four"` but only has `@"Three"`.

Comment: I think I'm having similar results with my arrays

Comment: Unfortunately this will not carry out the task requested. It will remove those objects that are in Array2 but will not add the objets that are only in Array2

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be using `NSString` objects as in your example code, I would iterate the first array and add those strings as keys to a `NSMutableDictionary` (e.g. `[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:str_object_here];`)

create a third array (your final output, use `[[NSArray alloc] initWithCapacity:min_count]` where min_count is size of your smaller array)

then iterate the second array and for each item, check if it exists as a key in the dictionary, if not add it to your third (final output) array

As dictionaries are optimized for key lookup (should be O(1) if I'm not mistaken, with proper use of hashing internally), you're moving from O(N^2) to O(N)